# Alterar local de download de arquivo

Tags: android

Consegui uma solução para baixar arquivos no android, porem ele baixa com um nome programado no codigo, e na raiz, queria que baixasse com o nome original do arquivo, e salvasse na pasta que eu quizesse, vejam o codigo:

```
public class DownloadFileDemo1 extends Activity {

    ProgressBar pb;
    Dialog dialog;
    int downloadedSize = 0;
    int totalSize = 0;
    TextView cur_val;
    String dwnload_file_path = "http://coderzheaven.com/sample_folder/sample_file.png";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 showProgress(dwnload_file_path);

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             downloadFile();
                        }
                      }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    void downloadFile(){

        try {
            URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //connect
            urlConnection.connect();

            //set the path where we want to save the file           
            File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
            //create a new file, to save the downloaded file 
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"downloaded_file.png");

            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

            //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
            totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pb.setMax(totalSize);
                }               
            });

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                // update the progressbar //
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);
                        float per = ((float)downloadedSize/totalSize) * 100;
                        cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int)per + "%)" );
                    }
                });
            }
            //close the output stream when complete //
            fileOutput.close();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // pb.dismiss(); // if you want close it..
                }
            });         

        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);        
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            showError("Error : IOException " + e);          
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
        }       
    }

    void showError(final String err){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(DownloadFileDemo1.this, err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    void showProgress(String file_path){
        dialog = new Dialog(DownloadFileDemo1.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Download Progress");

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        text.setText("Downloading file from ... " + file_path);
        cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
        cur_val.setText("Starting download...");
        dialog.show();

        pb = (ProgressBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        pb.setProgress(0);
        pb.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progress));  
    }
}
```

Como altero para ficar com o nome padrao do arquivo, e em uma pasta especificada?

Comment: O que você já tentou? Assim fica parecendo que você colou o código aqui e quer que alguém programe pra você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter o nome do arquivo você pode fazer algo assim:

```
String fileName = dwnload_file_path.substring(dwnload_file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, dwnload_file_path.length());
```

Ou então utilizar a classe [`FilenameUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) (*Apache Commons IO*).

E salvar em um diretório diferente da raiz do cartão SD, como está sendo feito, basta incluir no restante da sua variável **SDCardRoot** (e que ficaria com o nome não muito apropriado), verificar a existência para poder ou não criar.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/meus_downloads");
File file = null;

if (!path.exists()) {
    if (path.mkdir()) {
        file = new File(path, fileName);
    }
} else {
    file = new File(path, fileName);
}
```

Comment: obrigado cara, funcionou